# How to apply javascript to more than one element in html document?

Tags: javascript, html

I just started learning HTML and Javascript, so this might turn out to be a dumb question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere where google sent me.

What I want to do:

I want to have something in my HTML document that takes an argument (a date), runs my javascript on it and then changes the colour and the text according to the argument.

What I have tried so far:

Working (but extremely stupid) solution:

```
  <p id="demo"> </p> 
  <script>
   d = new Date();
   i = new Date(2014,0,19); //This is my "argument"
   var timesince = Math.floor((d.getTime() - i.getTime())/1000/60);
   var unit = "min";
   var colour = '#AAA';
   if (timesince > 60){
     timesince = Math.floor(timesince/60);
     unit = "h";
     if (timesince > 7) colour = '#a46744';
   }
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = timesince.toString()+unit;
   document.getElementById("demo").style.color = colour;
  </script>
```

But obviously, with this I would have to make one script for each element where I want to use this, and think of a new id every time, and change the hard-coded argument in the copy-pasted scripts individually. Which is crazy.

So, I thought about converting this into a function, and calling it for each element, but I don't know how. Or if that is even possible. All examples I found where for clicking like this:

```
 <a href=javascript:function()>Click</a>
```

Which is not at all what I want.

What I am looking for is a way to have something like this:

```
 <selfdefinedtag arguments=(2014,0,23)></selfdefinedtag>
```

which is then processed by the script above, only that `i` from the script is not hard-coded, but initialised by the values in `arguments`. And the colour and text is supposed to be different for each element.

So my questions are:

How can I convert `i` into an actual argument? (I am especially unsure about this Date() construct.)

How can I apply my script to more than one element with different arguments?

If you have general criticisms of my code about best practices and the like, I would be happy to hear them. I am not emotionally attached to what I have produced so far, so rip it apart all you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a function out of your code...

```
function changeElem(y1,m1,d1,elem){
 d = new Date();
   i = new Date(y1,m1,d1,0,0,0); //This is my "argument"
   var timesince = Math.floor((d.getTime() - i.getTime())/1000/60);
   var unit = "min";
   var colour = '#AAA';
   if (timesince > 60){
     timesince = Math.floor(timesince/60);
     unit = "h";
     if (timesince > 7) colour = '#a46744';
   }
   elem.innerHTML = timesince.toString()+unit;
   elem.style.color = colour;
}
```

To apply it to all `a` elements just do...

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

[].forEach.call(elem, function(e){
   var y = +e.getAttribute("data-y");
   var m = +e.getAttribute("data-m");
   var d = +e.getAttribute("data-d");
   changeElem(y,m,d,e);
});
```

(I used `+` unary operator to convert the string to numberical value, `getAttribute` will fetch the data attributes.)

And the `a` tag should be like

```
<a href="..." data-y="2014" data-m="0" data-d="19">...</a>
```

Comment: But the click part was exactly what I don't want. I just want the text to be there, like my original code, only not tied to one specific element. How do I call the function without the `href=`?

Comment: So you want the text and color to be their as soon as the page loads?

Comment: You want to change all the `a` elements?

Comment: That's close to what I want, but I want different arguments for each element, so I could have something like this: `<selfdefinedtag arguments=(2014,0,23)></selfdefinedtag>`, which then somehow magically gets processed by the function, with a different argument for every time I'm using it...

Comment: Where in the HTML document does the second script go? (The one with `var elem = ...` ) Also, I think you're missing an opening curly bracket for you function.

Comment: Both the scripts should be at bottom of HTML page. Second after first. Thanks for notifying curly bracket.

Comment: Hm, somehow the variables y, d, and m stay undefined, although data-y etc. seem to contain the data. And I get a TypeError with "this.getAttribute is not a function"

Comment: `this` seems to refer to the document and not to an element in the list. Which is probably why getAttribute is not defined. Anyway, I'll upvote for helping me this far (thanks a lot!), and if I can verify that this (or some slight modification of this) works, I'll accept :)

Comment: Yes just replace `this` with `e`.

Comment: Here is the working fiddle of the code you want.. http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/5hzrdqq2/10/ If it solves your problem please consider voting it up and marking it as correct answer.